# Player.seekTo is not a function

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I have the following init:

```
Player.init(element.id, playerId, () => {
    this.onReady(videoId, socket)
})
```

and callback:

```
onReady(videoId, socket){
    let msgContainer = document.getElementById("msg-container")
    let msgInput     = document.getElementById("msg-input")
    let postButton   = document.getElementById("msg-submit")
    let vidChannel   = socket.channel("videos:" + videoId)

    postButton.addEventListener("click", e => {
        let payload = {body: msgInput.value, at: Player.getCurrentTime()}
        vidChannel.push("new_annotation", payload)
            .receive("error", e => console.log(e) )
        msgInput.value = ""
    })

    msgContainer.addEventListener("click", e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        let seconds = e.target.getAttribute("data-seek") ||
                      e.target.parentNode.getAttribute("data-seek")
        if (!seconds) { return }

        Player.seekTo(seconds)
    })

    ...
}
```

However the Player.seekTo function fails with `_player2.default.seekTo is not a function` while the Player.getCurrentTime() function call works just as expected.

edit: I have also tried it with the seekahead parameter, same result.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_controls) of YouTube, the `player.seekTo(seconds:Number, allowSeekAhead:Boolean)` has two parameter that you need to set.

- The `seconds` parameter that identifies the time to which the player should advance.

And

- The `allowSeekAhead` parameter determines whether the player will make a new request to the server if the `seconds` parameter specifies a time outside of the currently buffered video data.

So your code must look like this:

```
msgContainer.addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    let seconds = e.target.getAttribute("data-seek") ||
    e.target.parentNode.getAttribute("data-seek")
    if (!seconds) { return }

    Player.seekTo(120, true)//120 seconds
})
```

For more information, check this SO question:

- [Youtube player JS API seekTo function not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955856/youtube-player-js-api-seekto-function-not-working)
- [YouTube iFrame API .seekTo() not a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813774/youtube-iframe-api-seekto-not-a-method)

Comment: Maybe I should have added this to the original question but I have tried it with and without the seekahead parameter, same result. Also I'm pretty sure calling JS functions without all the parameters doesn't throw with `is not a function`. Actually if you try for example "hi".replace("hi") it only returns undefined. But I'll change my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

I  know this is an old question, but I just struggled with this, too.
Here's what I ran into.

In my HTML code, I had

```
<iframe id="player" type="text/html"
    width="640"
    height="390"
    src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/...?enablejsapi=1&origin=https://[my_domain].com/"
    frameborder="1"
></iframe>
```

It was the `&origin= ...` part of the src attribute. Mixing HTTPS and HTTP led to the issue. Even though the [YouTube API reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) has this example code:

```
<iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://example.com"
  frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

This is no longer current. HTTPS must be used to cooperate with some browsers, especially mobile.